# How to manage catalog display of images for Commerce 2 product variation

Tags: 8, commerce

I have created a custom product type and its variations are created with attribute 'Size'. If I create a new product with its multiple images, then the catalog view shows these multiple images instead of a single image.

[image]

Below is the Product type variation 'Manage display' settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In future anyone need the answer, The image fields's format to be set to 'Image delta'. If image delta value set to 0 then the first image will be displayed and if it is set to 1 then the second image is displayed and so on.

Delta appears for the fields that has multiple values and delta refers to the order by which it appears.